# Texture as emission map? (Cycles, Smoke)

Tags: smoke-simulation

I want to use a texture as an emission map for a smoke simulation to use as a (hopefully) 3D animatable cloud map (using the other force effectors to move the cloud bands).

Apparently, it is possible to use *a* texture in either but *not the node texture*, at least that I am aware. Is there a work around to this?

[image: Texture shows up in the texture tab]

[image: texture does not show up in *Smoke Flow Advanced*]

Comment: Make sure your domain has high enough smoke resolution

Comment: [why-can-i-not-edit-object-texture-nodes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24881/why-can-i-not-edit-object-texture-nodes)